# Split a delimited string into an object

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I find myself using often the following pattern

```
var line = "12|John Doe"
var pieces = line.split("|")
var user = {
   id : pieces[0],
   name : pieces[1]
} 
console.log(user)
```

How would you use underscore to make this more concise and elegant ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Using Underscore:

```
var user = _.object(['id', 'name'], line.split('|'));

console.log(user); // Object {id: "12", name: "John Doe"}
```

Above code explained:

```
var keys = ['id', 'name'];         // plain array of user field names
var values = line.split('|');      // splits line string to array of values
var user = _.object(keys, values); // joins both arrays as an object
```

Read more about [underscore's *_.object* here](http://underscorejs.org/#object).

### Using Lodash:

Lodash equivalent method is [_.zipObject](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject).

```
var user = _.zipObject(['id', 'name'], line.split('|'));
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse the string to an object, you can use JS [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or underscore's [_.reduce()](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce):

```
function str2Obj(delimiter, props, str) {
    return str.split(delimiter)
        .reduce(function (obj, value, index) { // you can use underscore's reduce instead
        obj[props[index]] = value;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}
```

Usage:

```
var str1 = "12|John Doe";
console.log(str2Obj('|', ['id', 'name'], str1));
```

However, if you often use the same delimiter, or you have to parse a large number of strings with the same properties, underscore's (or loadsh's) [_.partial()](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) is very handy:

```
var str2 = "13|John Smith";
var str3 = "id|address|phone";

/** create a partially applied function with the '|' delimiter **/
var strToObjWithDelimiter = _.partial(str2Obj, '|');

console.log(strToObjWithDelimiter(['id', 'name'], str1));

console.log(strToObjWithDelimiter(['id', 'address', 'phone'], str3));

/** create a partially applied function with the '|' delimiter, and a props list **/
var userStr2Obj = _.partial(strToObjWithDelimiter, ['id', 'name']);

console.log([str1, str2].map(userStr2Obj)); // you can use _.map() as well
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/v0qdkyz8/4/) - inspect the bottom left panel to see results in console.